# Typescript method return type based on optional param property function

Tags: typescript, type-inference, optional-parameters, conditional-types

Trying to create a simple util that would either:

- return in the given array as-is
- or transformed based on an optional param given.
  Here is the code:

```js
type MapperFn<T, U> =  (val: T) => U;

interface mapperOpts<T,U> {
  cb?: MapperFn<T,U>
}

interface mapper {
  map<T, U, Z extends mapperOpts<T,U>>(arr: Array<T>, opts: Z): Z extends { cb: MapperFn<T,U> } ? U[]: T[];
}

const obj: mapper = {
  map: (arr, { cb }) => {
    if (!cb) return arr;
    return arr.map(cb);
  }
}

const arr: number[] =[1,2,3];

const result = obj.map(arr, {cb: (element) => element.toString() }); // should be typed as `string[]`

const result2 = obj.map(arr, { cb: (element) => element+1 }); // should be typed as `number[]`

const result3 = obj.map(arr, {}); // should be types as `number[]`
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
Type '<T, U, Z extends mapperOpts<T, U>>(arr: T[], { cb }: Z) => T[] | U[]' is not assignable to type '<T, U, Z extends mapperOpts<T, U>>(arr: T[], opts: Z) => Z extends { cb: MapperFn<T, U>; } ? U[] : T[]'.
  Type 'T[] | U[]' is not assignable to type 'Z extends { cb: MapperFn<T, U>; } ? U[] : T[]'.
    Type 'T[]' is not assignable to type 'Z extends { cb: MapperFn<T, U>; } ? U[] : T[]'.
```

Note that `result` and `result2` are marked as `unknown[]` which probably means argument type inference from callback function is not working correctly.

What am I missing?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmSAnAYgOwDwBUA0UCqAfFALxRQAUAbnADYBcUWAlKcfgNwBQXAlmsAhIAZnADG0ALYJkAeTDAAzthxEoAby7kxAIwD8jeIiHoVRLgF8e-QSPFSZQjVqjSwKgngBaUCAA9BNAATRVdHJHklM0JCCjgkJEYAQQS4EGxCPAB7BUVGL2Z83wCIYND1KF1DcNNcNQsoPQIAbQBdRiw27isuMSy0RWAoLJ0AK0Y3ZFJncjdGOIS8Ct0oC1YSYk1ycl5hSgBCXVYkCGAAVyQ0KHikbm2oE-PL64SAOjcKI7vVyx4+gaGN0YaDOkh0QjapGaAEYcAAmHAAZla3F6-UGDwgijOtCGZBGo3eCAWSCWVUoEFoEEkpWA62IlOptNewCyAGVgEh+ABzCisNYcKAAeiFUEUAAssjiglBwVBQJAZXBQgADQZctDctoqv7ooYnbG4uHTAlEsAkpaVHTzRk0gT03xUu3AADU0NWzEFIrFkulsugCogStVILBENaOrRAMxhuAiJNYzNFo0AuFoolUtoMrlgdCyqgKtD4KQ2qAA)

Comment: There's no reasonable inference site for `U` as a separate type parameter; you'd be better off just leaving it out and inferring it from `Z`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7gXRN).  Does that meet your needs?  (I don't understand some of your use cases, where `result2` would be `number[]` despite being identical to `result1` in every way, or why you expect `number` but not `number[]` out of `result3`.  Halp!  If these are mistakes please fix them so you have a true [mre]).  If so I'll write up an answer; if not, please elaborate about what doesn't work for you.

Comment: Sorry about that! I had pasted the wrong link. I have corrected the source code and the typescript playground link. I saw your link and it seems to be what I want! I initially started with this: https://tsplay.dev/WPjqqN which worked properly and thought I could move on from there. Could you please explain a bit more the **no reasonable inference site for U as a separate type parameter** or point me to a source so I can better understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specifics of how [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument inference works doesn't seem to be particularly well documented, aside from the [now obsolete TypeScript Language Specification](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/44c63a757e06abcc3f5812e7b762400ff567c186/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#3117-type-inference).

But in general, when the compiler sees a call to a function with a call signature of (say) `func<T, U, V>(x: F<T, U>, y: G<T, V>): H<U, V>;` of the form `c = func(a, b)`, it needs to try to infer the type parameters `T`, `U`, and `V` from the types of the values `a`, `b`, and `c`.  To infer `U`, the compiler would need to examine the types of `a` and `c`, since the parameter `x` and the return type both depend on `U`.  So `x` and the return type are potential *inference sites* for `T`.  On the other hand, it would be hopeless to try to use `b` to infer anything about `U`, because the type of the `y` parameter does not refer to `U` at all.  That is, `y` is not an inference site for `U`.

Not all inference sites are treated equally, and some are harder to infer than others.  Return types are usually poor inference sites, since often the compiler does not know the expected return type... if you wrote `const c = func(a, b);` you are asking the compiler to infer the type of `c`, so the return type of `func()` is not known.  You'd only be able to use the return type in a case where, for example, `c` is already of a known type like `const c: SomeType = func(a, b);`.

And the more complex the type function involving the type parameter, the less useful of an inference site it can be.  For something like `f<T>(x: T): void`, a call to `f(a)` will easily infer `T` to be the type of `a`.  But for something like `g<T>(x: T[keyof T]): void` it will be nearly impossible to infer `T` from `g(a)`.  In the former case, you are inferring `T` from a value of the same type.  Easy.  In the latter case, inferring `T` from a value of the union of the properties of that type.  Not obvious how you'd even begin.  Other type functions tend to fall somewhere in between those extremes.  If you run into problems, your best bet is to simplify the type functions in the inference sites.

Finally, some places are not used as inference sites at all.  A function signature like `h<T, U extends T>(u: U): void` does not have an inference site for `T`.  [Generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) are not consulted when inferring type parameters.  Perhaps you might want the compiler to infer `U` from what's passed to `h()`, and then infer `T` from `U`, but that just isn't what happens.  `T` will surely fail to be inferred and will fall back to something like `unknown`.

For issues where this comes up, you can look at [microsoft/TypeScript#38183](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38183), [microsoft/TypeScript#31529](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31529), and probably many others (I would search for "inference site").

---

So, all of that being said, my suggestion for your `map()` method is this:

```
interface Mapper {
  map<T, Z extends MapperOpts<T, any>>(arr: Array<T>, opts: Z):
    Z extends { cb: MapperFn<T, infer U> } ? U[] : T[];
}
```

There was no reasonable inference site for `U` in the previous version.  Instead, we will just infer `T` and `Z` from `arr` and `opts`.  This will most likely succeed.  From that, we can use `Z` to extract `U` via explicit [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types).

Let's see how it works:

```
const result = obj.map(arr, { cb: (element) => element.toString() }); // string[]
const result2 = obj.map(arr, { cb: (element) => element + 1 }); // number[]
const result3 = obj.map(arr, {}); // number[]
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=33#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmSAnAYgOwDwBUA0UCqAfFALxQAUAbnADYBcUWAlKcfgNwBQnAlmsBCQAzOAGNo8RIIDyYYAGdseIlADenKFFEAjAPwNJydEoKFOAX258BwsRITI1GqAFsEJgFpQIADwFoAE3lYBxk5RVwoODQQQkJyOCQkBgBBJLgQbEI8AHtwhg8mOmdNL19-ILUtbQNQ1ExIviFBUyhzKF0CAG0AXSgGLF6uS05RHLR5YCgc7QArWqkkUidNNzAGBKS8VWq2lhJidU1NHiEKAEIdFiQIYABXJDQopK5jqBv7x+ekADo18iurzaFm4YwmU0SySgaDuLm0gl6yy6AEY8AAmPAAZh6XFG40m7wg8juNCmZBmsz+CE2SG21Q2EBoEBcEH4+2IjOZrOAP2AOQAysAkHwAObkFjmJjsKAAehlUEmwrQIt6ePBhOJpLRywpVLANLpOgZTJZbNY3hN3KgAGooMi9tK5dDYfCkKqwQSbprgJidXM9Qa1JLHfKYXCET0gA)

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! I am impressed!

Comment: One thing to ask. In the code `map<T, U, Z extends mapperOpts<T,U>>(arr: Array<T>, opts: Z): Z extends { cb: MapperFn<T,U> } ? U[]: T[];` wouldn't the usage of `U` in `mapperOpts<T,U>` be considered as an inference site?

Comment: No, because "generic constraints are not consulted when inferring type parameters" (see the paragraph that starts with that text).  The `mapperOpts<T, U>` only appears in a constraint position in `Z extends mapperOpts<T, U>`. You might hope that `opts` would let `Z` be inferred and then `Z` would let `U` be inferred but it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Got it... Thanks!

Comment: Hey! I really appreciate your time, but while I tried to implement the minimal example we had into a class in my code I couldn't make it. I tried to also do it in our example and it failed there as well. I would be really grateful if you could take a look at this updated example with classes: https://tsplay.dev/Nd4BQN and see why the same implementation is not working

Comment: If we explicitly cast the return type in `Test` class implementation it works: https://tsplay.dev/N7g7RN but I wasn't sure there is something I am doing wrong and it doesn't work when in class as opposed to object

Comment: That is https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912, it's an open issue in TS.  It's nearly impossible for the compiler to verify that any particular value is of a conditional type that depends on an unresolved generic type parameter.  Note that if you need more time here from someone you should probably post a new question (after searching for existing ones) instead of relying on the comment section of an already answered question.  Good luck!